# take one in foreach loop instead of all

Tags: php

I use the code below to iterate all div's on a page with id = news using PHPScraper. Is it possible to only take the first div it find so that the array only contains one entry? I was thinking of maybe (if possible) only take one in the foreach loop like you can do in c# (myList.Take(1))

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://localhost/test.html');

//collect all news entries into an array
$myArray = array();
if(!empty($dom)) {
    $divClass = $title = '';

    foreach($dom->find("div[id*=news]") as $divClass) {
```

Comment: What "PHPScraper" tool are you referring to? It's likely it has a way of fetching a single element rather than array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [break](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) to stop the loop from continuing after you've added the first div.

Something like this:

```
foreach($dom->find("div[id*=news]") as $divClass) {
    $myArray[] = $divClass; // Just assuming you're doing something like this
    break;
}
```

***Side note:*** The code `$divClass = $title = '';` before the loop doesn't serve any purpose in your posted code.  The variable `$divClass` will be completely overwritten on each iteration of your `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io).

To grab only one element, you can simply [pass `0` as the second argument of `find`](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_find):

```
$firstDiv = $dom->find('div[id*=news]', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($dom->find("div[id*=news]") as $divClass) {
/// work here
break;
}
```

break; statement is used to stop loop from further processing. So if you use it directly then loop would only execute once.